# Please suggest me soldering station

Tags: soldering

I want to buy soldering station. Can you suggest me some?
I don't want to buy some very expensive station (like Weller), but I don't want also some cheap station. I will use it firstly for some "basic" soldering and then for SMD. What do you think about Hakko FX888?
Here is one on ebay http://www.ebay.com/itm/220V-OEM-HAKKO-FX888-65W-Electronic-SMD-SMT-Soldering-Station-Iron-Phone-Repair-/311122279863?hash=item4870553db7:g:ehYAAOSw6EhUM5W3
Is this real price for original station?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with these kinds of questions. They can be kind of opinionated and not really related to electronic design.

In my opinion Hakko is the best brand for the job (assuming non-industrial applications). If you are very new to electronics and soldering I would highly recommend buying a cheap one (like $15-$20) just to get some experience with. The one that you have listed is my personal favorite. Be warned that in certain applications it will be most desirable to have a digital soldering station. You can most definitely get by with an adjustable analog if you do not have access to one, but depending on what level of work you are trying to accomplish you might need one.

I am unsure of what you mean by "is this really the price." This particular seller is selling more than just the station including tweezers, solder, and different tips (which you will definitely want if working with SMD). If you just want the station it's about $80-$90, but I think they might just be selling the digital for around $90 now.

Again I don't want to sound unkind, but if you are looking for product reviews go to another site. This site is reserved for electronic design only.

Comment: You really shouldn't answer questions that are so blatantly off topic.

Comment: I agree, but it doesn't hurt anyone to throw out a quick answer so long as they're made aware they shouldn't make the same mistake in the future.